# Отбитие объекта от закруглённых углов PyGame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Есть два объекта- Платформа и мяч. Платформа имеет закруглённые углы. Дабы мяч не отбивался от воздуха, я сделал два круга внутри платформы - верхний и нижний. Пытался сделать проверку на касание о угол на каждые 10 пикселей мяча, но 
он просто пролетает сквозь угол. Подскажите, как можно реализовать отскок от закруглённых углов?

```
while gameStart is True:

    MainSurface = pygame.Surface(WinXY)
    MainSurface.fill((8, 54, 77))

    # Creating platforms and ball
    PI = pygame.Surface((49, 325))
    PI.fill((8, 54, 77))
    PItopCircle = pygame.draw.circle(PI, (0, 0, 0, 0), (TopCircX, TopCircY), CRad)
    PIbotCircle = pygame.draw.circle(PI, (0, 0, 0, 0), (24, 301), CRad)
    PI.blit(UPpic, (0, 0))
    MainSurface.blit(PI, (UPx, UPy))

    if EPm is True:
        EPy = BallY / 2 + 80
    EP = pygame.Surface((49, 325))
    EP.fill((8, 54, 77))
    EPtopCircle = pygame.draw.circle(EP, (0, 0, 0, 0), (TopCircX, TopCircY), CRad)
    EPbotCircle = pygame.draw.circle(EP, (0, 0, 0, 0), (24, 301), CRad)
    EP.blit(EPpic, (0, 0))
    MainSurface.blit(EP, (EPx, EPy))

    Ball = pygame.image.load('data\\ball.png')
    Ball.get_rect()
    MainSurface.blit(Ball, (BallX, BallY))

    pygame.draw.rect(MainSurface, (0, 0, 0), (WinX // 2 - 50, 0, 100, 50))

    win.blit(MainSurface, (0, 0))

    # Movement of user platform
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and UPy > WinY // 100:
        UPy -= UPySpeed[1]
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and UPy < WinY // 20 + WinY // 2:
        UPy += UPySpeed[1]

    for tW in range(1):
        throughWalls = random.randint(0, 1)

    # Ball movement
    for i in range(1):

        # Testing for pushes on screen to initialize ball movement
        for startGame in pygame.event.get():
            if startGame.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= WinX // 2 - 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= WinY // 2 - 50:
                    if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] <= WinX // 2 + 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= WinY // 2 + 50:
                        ballStart = True

                # Testing for pause
                if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] >= WinX // 2 - 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] >= 0:
                    if pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] <= WinX // 2 + 50 and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] <= 50:
                        ballStart = False

            # -----------------------------------
            if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            # -----------------------------------

        if ballStart is True:

            # Changing direction
            if BallX <= UPx + 50 and BallX >= UPx and BallY + 40 >= UPy + 24 and BallY <= UPy + 300:
                Right = True
                Left = False

            if BallX + 80 >= EPx and BallX + 80 <= EPx + 50 and BallY + 40 >= EPy + 24 and BallY <= EPy + 300:
                Left = True
                Right = False

            if Right:
                BallX += BallXSpeed

            if Left:
                BallX -= BallXSpeed



            if BallX <= TopCircX + 24 and BallX >= TopCircX - 24:
                print('True')


            if BallY <= 5:
                Up = False
                Down = True
            if BallY >= WinY - 85:
                Up = True
                Down = False

            if Up:
                BallY -= BallYSpeed

            if Down:
                BallY += BallYSpeed

            pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно постоянно проверять на столкновение - достаточно заранее рассчитать, в какой момент и в какой точке случится первое столкновение. После столкновения сделать то же самое для нового направления  и т.д.

В прошлой ветке я давал [ссылку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765161/drawing-a-line-within-boundaries-from-point-x-y-with-a-given-angle), как это можно рассчитать для случая луча, идущего изнутри прямоугольника.